# JDK Installation Error in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java9-installer is already the newest version (9.0.4-1~webupd8~0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java9-installer (9.0.4-1~webupd8~0) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk9-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 9...
--2018-02-12 17:41:38--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.4+11/c2514751926b4512b076cc82f959763f/jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.57.201.44
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.57.201.44|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2018-02-12 17:41:39--  (try: 2)  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.4+11/c2514751926b4512b076cc82f959763f/jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.57.201.44|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2018-02-12 17:41:41--  (try: 3)  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.4+11/c2514751926b4512b076cc82f959763f/jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.57.201.44|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2018-02-12 17:41:44--  (try: 4)  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.4+11/c2514751926b4512b076cc82f959763f/jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.57.201.44|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2018-02-12 17:41:48--  (try: 5)  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.4+11/c2514751926b4512b076cc82f959763f/jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.57.201.44|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Giving up.

download failed
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java9-installer (--configure):
```

Comment: Please provide some description and format you post. It is hard to read it.

Comment: from logs it looks like your network connection to oracle.com was interrupted. Is there some kind of proxy between your box and the internet?

Comment: I'm a bit more concerned about the 31 packages you didn't upgrade, and the 6 that aren't fully installed or removed. Anyway, "Connection reset by peer" isn't really programming related.

Comment: this question should probably go to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml#install

Comment: i am not getting any solution at askubuntu.com

Comment: problem with the internet connection :)

Answer (score 1):

> Caution :- Please Read your error logs carefully..

If you able to see your error message this shows.

```
-2018-02-12 17:41:48--  (try: 5)
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Giving up.
```

It means there is problem with your internet connection. Because, there are 5 attempts had been done to connect and download it.

> Assumption :-  Due to some proxy/sock issue, `apt-get` won't be able to connect to the Internet.

It is usually when a firewall drop the connection or the host is a proxy to another host, and the other host drop

Thanks.